# Sudden error accessing custom settings in SalesForce

Tags: salesforce

We use custom settings in a SalesForce app. We access it like so:

```
MySettings__c settings = MySettings__c.getOrgDefaults();
```

This was working fine, but today the app completely crashed. By that I mean the page doesn't load at all, I just get a white screen telling me an internal error occurred. We traced it down to this line of code - when it is commented out the page loads as well as it can without those settings (but at least it loads).

Running that single line of code in the System Log (using the Execute functionality) also causes a report of Internal System Error. The only thing the system log reports is "FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error." The Apex code modal reports "Internal System Error: 1018505045-332 (-920440070)"

The setting has values for the organization - we've also tried deleting the settings and recreating them to no affect. So far SalesForce has been no help beyond telling us to ask on their website.

This is very frustrating as it was working fine on Friday and today it was broken before anyone touched anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the apiVersion of the affected code back to version 21.0.  We had the same issue and making this change has provided an effective workaround.

Comment: This did end up being the problem and we were able to confirm it with SFDC support. I don't know exactly what the bug is but this at least fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a platform error. Whenever you get those you should report them to SFDC support and they will be able to see further internal logging to sort it out.

Nothing anyone out here can do to help I am afraid.

Paul

Comment: That's pretty much what I've determined. Unfortunately SFDC isn't too good about providing support for these kinds of errors - at least in my experience so far. It took over 24 hours just to get this into the hands of someone who knew what I was talking about. 36 hours after THAT and I'm still waiting to hear what the issue is.

Comment: I usually expect a minimum of 3 days before it gets in the hands of the right person.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Salesforce's infrastructure, which has been reported resolved.  If you're still seeing this error with API version 22.0, you should create a case with salesforce support.